# In Windows, Meld can't save to directories mounted via SSHFS-Win. How to enable that?

Tags: windows, sshfs, meld

I have mounted the root directory of one of my Linux boxes to a drive letter in Windows (in this case, `P:`), using [Sshfs-Win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/). I have imported the directory using SSH root credentials, and therefore, in Windows File Explorer, I can read and write everywhere in `P:`.

Now I would like compare two folders on `P:`, using [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) for Windows. It correctly compares the folders and shows the differences between them, and also shows the differences in each file, as you would expect from a graphical diff tool.

However, when I alter a file, `meld` can't save it afterwards. The error message is (in the following, `<file path>` is a placeholder for the actual file name it displays):

```
Could not save file P:\<file path>
Couldn't save file due to:
g-io-error-quark: Error opening file "P:\<file path>": Permission denied (14)
```

However, as said above, I definitely have all permissions on drive `P:`; I can alter, delete and re-create the file in question via Windows File Explorer.

Is there some trick to enable `meld` to save files on drive letters where a SSHFS is mounted?

Comment: This is an open issue. See https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/issues/277.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about it yet.